# Default iphone keyboard does not close for entire application if it is opened in iframe in ionic 3

Tags: iphone, iframe, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic-keyboard

i have used **cordova--plugin-ionic-keyboard** default plugin in my hybrid  ios 
application in ionic 3 .
when i open a **payment gateway link** by using **iframe** and i click on the textbox button for writing a card details keyboard will appear but if any case i want to go back after opening a keyboard then keyboard is not closed or hide for whole app then i have to close the app and start again.

i have searched a lot of things on internet but i can not get a appropriate answer which works for me.

i have tried out **hide() method**  of plugin but whichever page i use this hide method that page is not open means app stop before the page on which i try hide method.

i also used in-app browser but still not work

Comment: hide() method is not working try close() method  check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54554838/10845300

Comment: but  close() method is not in the lastest version of plugin .

Comment: if you are using ionic 3 then then close function should work i tested it and it is working

Comment: no . when i write a close() method it shows me red line (error) . can you tell your plugin name and version ?

Comment: I have shared a link abouve check it ,there you find plugin as well btw no need to add any plugin ionic native have there plugin

Comment: yup i know that  no need to add any plugin for keyboard  but i upgrade that plugin . Here the link :- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/keyboard/

Comment: okay .i will try and thanks for the support

Comment: After that if it is not working then i recomand you to downgrade you ionic version to @3.9.2,because i am using this version and it works it

Comment: brother , i have tried but whichever page i use this close method that page is not open means app stop before the page on which i try close method.e.g i put method on 5th navigator page then when i click on 4th navigator page 's button for moving on 5th but it doesn't redirect and i remove then it works fine why this happened?

Comment: can you share your code below so i can check it?

Comment: constructor(public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private iab: InAppBrowser , public sanitizer : DomSanitizer , public alertCtrl: AlertController , public platform: Platform,public keyboard : Keyboard) {
   
    this.pay= this.navParams.get("payment");
   this.browser = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.pay);
   console.log(this.pay);
     
  }

gotohome()
  {
    this.keyboard.close();
    this.navCtrl.pop();
  }

Comment: hey brother , can you help me in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568108/apk-is-installed-on-device-but-immediately-close-after-clicking-in-ionic